# How to reuse mock objects in Perl unit tests?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, code-reuse

I have a bunch of unit tests for my module, and I find that I copy the same mock and setup code from one to the other. How can I DRY that up and reuse the mock code?

I've placed this simple mock object next to my tests:

```
package MockObject;
1;
```

If I just say `use MockObject;` in the test case, `make test` cannot find MockObject. Makes sense; after all, it's not installed system wide and it's not next to the module under test.

I can run my tests with `prove -I lib -I t t/*.t` but I'd like to keep `make test`, if only for the laziness of typing a few characters less.

Since the mock object isn't a full module and shouldn't be officially installed anyway, I cannot and don't want to set `TEST_REQUIRES` in Makefile.PL.

Adding `test => { FILES => 't/*.t', INC => 't/' }` to Makefile.PL didn't help.

How can I (simply) reuse Perl mock code with the MakeMaker generated Makefile?

Comment: Either set PERL5LIB to include your t directory, or just `use lib` inside your test file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup PERL5LIB or add `use lib` in your script. I found [FindBin package](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.7/lib/FindBin.pm) useful for setting up the lib path for tests.

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/../lib";
```

Where:

```
$Bin - path to bin directory from where script was invoked
```

Comment: I am just using `use lib 't';`, which I still have to copy to very test case, but that is much better than copying all the mock code around, doesn't mess with global settings, and works.